# Multiple regression and post-hoc analysis

Tags: multiple-regression, post-hoc, model-comparison

Dependent Variable(s): cognitive test

Independent Variable:

Sex (covariate), Age (covariate),
working memory,
long-term memory test,
interaction(working memory: long-term memory)

However, the interaction was not significant.

so I want to investigate whether Working memory or long-term memory would be more
influential to cognitive tests after controlling for SEX and AGE

```
cognitive test1 ~ SEX + AGE + Working Memory(sig)

cognitive test1 ~ SEX + AGE + Long term memory(non-sig)
```

is it correct to call it that we conducted a sensitivity analysis?

or are there any better ways?

like, is it better to compare model fit such as AIC and BIC?